# unmarshalling @XMLElement with same name attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to make use of JAXB for an application that already writes XML in a certain format. I have to keep with the format for backward compatibility issues.

I have the following segment of code in a class:

```
@XmlElement( name = "field" )
private StudyIdentifier2 studyIdentifier;

@XmlElement( name = "field" )
private List<GenericField> demographicsFields = new ArrayList<GenericField>();
```

This code will correctly write the following XML:

```
    <field>
        <value>2</value>
        <XMLtag>id</XMLtag>
    </field>
    <field>
        <value>JAMES</value>
        <XMLtag>patient_name</XMLtag>
    </field>
    <field>
        <value>This is a test</value>
        <XMLtag>study_description</XMLtag>
    </field>
```

However when I attempt to unmarshall it, I  just get my `StudyIdentifier2` object containing the last XML field details, the `study_description` and the `demographicsFields` `ArrayList` has just got nulls in it. I assume it's because I'm specifying the same name value in the `@XMLElement` annotation so it can't unmashall correctly. However I need them to both be called `<field>`. Is it possible to give them both the same name, or do they have to be different for it to unmarshall correctly?

Could well be a very simple solution, I've yet to get my head fully round how JAXB works.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing within this XML that can be used to programatically determine which type of "field" it is (either a `StudyIdentifier2` or a `GenericField`).  I probably wouldn't even be able to organize this XML "by hand", ignoring any possible limitations or difficulties with JAXB.

It is difficult to see exactly what's happening here without seeing the class definition for `GenericField`.  However, more than likely, yes, you would need to give them different names (changing your XML and probably causing some of the backwards compatibility issues you mentioned) if you want this to be unmarshalled "correctly".  Alternatively, if `GenericField` can represent all 3 fields from your sample XML, what if you just remove the `studyIdentifier`, and let `demographicsFields` represent everything for both marshalling and unmarshalling - after maybe renaming it to something more appropriate like `genericFields`?

Now if you know for example that `StudyIdentifer2` should always be read from the 3rd `<field/>` in the XML, and everything else needs to go into the `demographicsFields`, please clarify that in your question, and we can probably find some additional options.